# Apache POI > handling Special formats?

Tags: apache-poi, locale

I am looking into generating an xlsx file, and, for certain cells, *apply a "Special"* (that is the exact word used in Excel, in Format Cells > Category) *category with a specific locale*. For instance, my local installation of Excel comes with "Social Insurance Number" for the locale "English (Canada)".

I have checked the POI API, Googled a bit and I am puzzled about how to do that. 
I have tried creating such cells manually (using Excel directly) then read them using POI.
If I apply getCellStyle().getDataFormat() to my cell, I am returned values equal or superior to 164. Which I guess means it is considered as something user-defined, since POI org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats#FIRST_USER_DEFINED_FORMAT_INDEX constant is 164.

Is what am trying to do achievable at all ? I do not even know where are Excel's Special types defined generally speaking. These do seem to be built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `Excel` number formats based on special format pattern. See [How to control and understand settings in the Format Cells dialog box in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/264372/how-to-control-and-understand-settings-in-the-format-cells-dialog-box).

To get what exact format patterns are needed for special formats one can apply the special format to a cell and then have a look at the corresponding custom format then.

The following is the special format "Social Insurance Number (CH)" - Switzerland:

[image] This is German `Excel` "Sonderformat" is "Special".

This corresponds to the custom format `000\.00\.000\.000`. You can deduct that by simply changing to category `Custom` in `Excel`'s dialog `Format Cells` - `Number`. Then read the pattern from text field below `Type:`:

[image] This is German `Excel` "Benutzerdefiniert" is "Custom".

So the general way is: First choose your special format in `Excel`'s  dialog `Format Cells` - `Number`. Then change the category to `Custom` and read the corresponding pattern from the text field below `Type:`.

If you have the number format pattern, this can be used using `apache poi` as follows:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelNumberFormat {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle specialSIN = workbook.createCellStyle();
   specialSIN.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("000\\.00\\.000\\.000"));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
   cell.setCellStyle(specialSIN);
   cell.setCellValue(12345678901d);

   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 14*256);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Your Social Insurance Number for the locale English (Canada) would must be:

```
...
specialSIN.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("000 000 000"));
...
cell.setCellValue(46454286);
...
```

Comment: Thank you.  One piece of the puzzle is still missing for me, though, you wrote "This corresponds to the custom format 000\.00\.000\.000:", but how could you deduce that ? (generally speaking: the SIN was just an example I picked. If we continue with this example, what I want to do is solve this problem without the external knowledge that SIN format is "000\.00\.000\.000" :))

Comment: @Toto: I thought the pictures would have shown this. You can deduct that by simply changing to category `Custom` in `Excel`'s dialog Format Cells - Number. Then read the pattern from text field below Type:

Comment: Ah, that totally flew over my head, sorry. Validating your answer, as that answers the initial question. Thank you !