# User Defined Special Formats returning same index for two different types

Tags: excel, apache-poi, user-defined-types

I have a program that is using the Apache POI to determine the Format Index returned for all built-in formats and all user-defined special formats.  The issue I am running into is that there are at least 15 indices that have multiple "Type" that are returning the index.  For example,

[image]

In this image, each of these two cells has a different type, e.g. [*Apache POI > handling Special formats?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891491/apache-poi-handling-special-formats), but both return the index 164 for User-Defined Special Format.  It would be expected that they would each have a different index #, as they are two different types of values (a number and date).

I understand that the Excel POI returns both of these as an `Integer`, and that I myself have to determine whether it's a number or a date (I'm doing that by looking at each Format Index and keeping a Map to reference keys); however most other User Defined Indices are one specific type when you look in the Excel dialogue box shown.

I have had the index returned in my program and have compared both types shown in the Excel Special Format dialogue box, and they are different.

Index #164 has the following type within the POI: `"$"#,##0_);[Red]\("$"#,##0\)`.  This kind of renders the index useless because it could either be a number OR a date.  Just wondering if I'm missing an extra step that could delineate it more to find out which of the two it is since the type is really smashing two different types together.

Comment: "both return the index 164 for User-Defined Special Format": Both in the same workbook the same time? I doubt that. The index 164 always is the index of the first user-defined number format in a workbook apart from the built-in number formats.

Comment: So if the first user-defined number format is a date format, then the 164 will be the index of that. If the first user-defined number format is a currency format, then the 164 will be the index of that. But if both the user-defined number formats are defined for the workbook the same time, then the indexes will be different. If user-defined date format was first and user-defined currency format was second, then user-defined date format will be 164 and user-defined currency format will be 165.

Comment: Hi, I didn't clarify that part, my apologies.  My program is being built to analyze any file selected by the user.  It does indeed only return the same format within a single workbook, but from workbook to workbook I get the same index (164) for as you said date and currency.